# Where do I put an external Java library in my program's directory structure?

Tags: java, libraries, directory-structure

I'm new to Java, and trying to figure out how to structure my program's files.

I've downloaded a library ([jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)), which contains both a `jar` and also zip of the Java source code.

So far, I've only got my program working by extracting jnotify's source to the top level directory of the program. So jnotify's source files are all over the place, and my program's code is in a subdirectory.

```
$ ls /path/to/project
CHANGELOG
inotify-syscalls.h
jnotify_64bit.dll
jnotify.dll
libnotify.so
my-projects-actual-files/
net/
README
... etc
```

I'm importing jnotify like so:

```
# myprogram/program.java
import net.contentobjects.jnotify.*;
... code body here ...
```

And running it by explicitly setting `java.library.path`:

```
$ java -Djava.library.path=. myprogram/Program
```

This feels wrong but I have no idea what the Java way of organising source files and libraries is.

How can I neaten my program's structure so that `jnotify` lives in something like `lib/jnotify` but can be imported, compiled and run sensibly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jar should just be on the class path, the library path specifies where the dll lives.

java -classpath lib/jnotify.jar;. -Djava.library.path=lib/ myprogram/Program

You shouldn't unzip the source code, unless you need to debug the jnotify code.

Comment: I'm having trouble compiling without extracting the source files. My `import net.contentobjects.jnotify.*` is failing with a 'package does not exist error'. Does this need to be modified? Is there another syntax for importing a `jar`? And do the `dll` and `so` files just go into the same directory as the `jar`? Thanks :)

Comment: The reason you are having problem compiling is because you need to give `-classpath lib/jnotify.jar;.` as a `javac` command option as well.

Comment: the jar and dll/so need not be in the same position. They can be anywhere... the classpath must have the jar path, and the java.library.path needs to have the directory (owner) of the dll/so.

Comment: Great, thanks! For anyone else reading this, `-classpath` uses `:` to separate directories instead of a `;` under *nix.